# Replacing texts in quanteda > 3.2.4

Tags: quanteda

while reviewing some old code I realized that texts(x) will be removed in future quanteda releases.

```
> test <- corpus("Hello, World")
> texts(test) <- gsub("World","world", texts(test))
Warning messages:
1: 'texts.corpus' is deprecated.
Use 'as.character' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
2: use the '[<-' replacement for a corpus object instead
```

However, I am unsure whether I understand the new way to replace texts in a corpus correctly. Is my MWE the correct new way?

```
test <- corpus(c("Hello, World","Hello, Box"))
test[] <- gsub("Hello","hello", as.character(test))
```

Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even simpler now:

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.5
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 71.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

test <- corpus(c("Hello, World", "Hello, Box"))
test <- gsub("Hello", "hello", test)
test
#> Corpus consisting of 2 documents.
#> text1 :
#> "hello, World"
#> 
#> text2 :
#> "hello, Box"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>